# Proper nesting - namespace collisions

Tags: html

I need a little advice on nesting HTML elements.  I have a general structure where `X` contains a `New` section (where I'll add form elements for creating an `X`) and a `List` section that displays whatever `X`s already exist:

```
<div id="X">
    <div id="New">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="List">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

now it turns out I need to have two on the page:

```
<div id="X">
...
</div>

<div id="Y">
...
</div>
```

so whilst I can differentiate the 2 `New`s like this:

```
#X #New {} /* in CSS */
$('#Y #New') /* in jQuery */
```

I'm left with the queasy feeling that `#New` should be unique in the document... so one alternative might be:

```
<div id="X">
    <div id="XNew">
    ...
    </div>
    <div id="XList">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

but then the notion of using `X` for nesting (as a namespace) seems moot since I've flattened the names... or perhaps another:

```
<div id="X">
    <div class="New">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="List">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

but here I'm using a class where I really mean to designate a single element.  How do you all do this sort of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IDs should **always** be unique. That's why they're called identifiers. Using a class is the correct solution in this case. Then you can easily reference the elements via `#X .New` and `#x .List` for example. This also makes it easier to apply common styles and behaviour to all `List` and `New` divs.

Comment: you mean `#X .New` (space separated) - don't you?

Comment: semantically, I would prefer #New, rather than .New since that element is not a class of elements... it is a specific element and unique, but within the context of its parent; ergo my confusion.

Comment: Yes about the space separation, that was a typo. Anyway, `#New` is not a unique element if you have two of them. Not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: what I'm trying to accomplish is an approach to my layouts that is semantically consistent.  `New` should not be a class because it's used to uniquely identify an element in the page.  The problem is that the name is global so I either need to disambiguate by pre-pending parent names, or break the rules, and I'm not happy with either approach.

Comment: I would strongly discourage considering breaking the rules as an option. You can either add a prefix to the ID or use classes. If the parent has some meaning, then I would say `#X .List` makes sense semantically. You're referring to the `List` contained within `#X`.

Comment: I agree, breaking the rules is a hornet's nest of issues, but `#X .List` is semantically incorrect as it indicates that I mean a class of elements within #X, and that's not what I mean.  `#X #List` would be more correct but since #List is global, I can't use it.  So I guess #XList will have to be it.